# Code executes when typed into console but not in script

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a javascript project i am running,and i have finished the first phase.The second phase requires for me to start by assigning a `variable` to a `dom` object.

I assigned the `variable` and it worked.Then i updated the `code` into my project `script`.Now,the problem is that whenever i run the `script` the `script` will execute but,the `variable` i assigned and updated into my `script` won't assign and the `code` line won't run.

```
    var element = document.getElementById('inputElement');
```

Every time i run that line in the `console` maybe by copy/paste or typing it personally it works but,the `code` won't execute when it is in a script.

Comment: Please show context in which it doesn't works.

Comment: Did you put that code in the `<head>` element and not inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event?

Comment: i ran the script directly in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the script with this assignment comes after the HTML element with id `inputElement`

Comment: explain better.

Comment: for example this would works `<div id="inputElem">hello</div><script src="some.js" />` but this would not `<script src="some.js" /><div id="inputElem">hello</div>`

Comment: the `dom` is not my `dom` i am working on the `dom` of a site like youtube or facebook.

Comment: try putting it inside DOMContentLoaded event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: whenever i copy/paste or type that line into the console it will fetch the element and assign the variable,but If i run the script containing that code in the console the code won't fetch the element and it won't assign the variable.

Comment: @IvakaZakuri **How** are you running the "script", that's what everyone is asking

Comment: @slebetman,i copy it from notepad and i paste in console.

Comment: @IvakaZakuri No, that is you running the code in the console. How are you running the "script" that cannot run? Did you include it in some html's `script` tag? That is the part everyone is not understanding

Comment: @IvakaZakuri - in other words, show us your non-working "script" - it must be a file right? Post it here. One line of code is not enough to debug your problem

Comment: @slebetman,read my post again and understand.

Comment: @IvakaZakuri You never specified how the script is running in your post. Is it simply via a `script` tag in an html file? If so where? In the `head`? In the `body`? At the end of `body`? Are you running it in an `onload` handler? These are questions necessary to answer your question but you have not provided any information